# Determine virtual host name on SSH connection (would be useful for virtual git hosting)

Tags: git, networking, ssh

I'm looking for a way to do what the HTTP Host: header does, except for SSH.

Imagine that `foo.example.com` and `bar.example.com` both resolve to `1.2.3.4`. How can I find out that a login occurred via `ssh git@foo.example.com` instead of `ssh git@bar.example.com`?

I'm finding `$SSH_CONNECTION` but it only has the IP addresses of client and server, not the hostnames.

P.S. What I'm really asking is how to make git virtual hosting work via the SSH transport. My client isn't ssh directly, but git invoking ssh. I understand virtual git hosting can probably made to work via HTTP (using Host:) and git-daemon (which seem to be told what the hostname was). But what about SSH? Otherwise how do I make (secure) commits work in a virtual hosting environment?

If not: any kludges that would approximate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is no, there is no equivalent of virtual hosts for openSSH afaik.

The question actually boils down to what difference you want to present to the clients logging in via `foo.example.com` and `bar.example.com` ?

I'm guessing that you just want to provide 2 independent set of root directories for hosting the git repositories for your client based on the host they use. If that be the case, you could ask each of the users to use different usernames instead thereby they get access to a different home directory with proper isolated permissions. git just uses the SSH protocol to store files on the server, so it should be really transparent.

If your case involves having multiple VMs on a single Xen or equivalent server, then you could look into setting up a SSH gateway to the multiple VMs from your Xen server as described in [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/329529/virtual-hosts-for-ssh) post.

Answer (score 0):

(**Future answer**) There seems to have been a [discussion](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/openssh/dev/55943) about adding this to SSH last year. The suggestion, for the `openssh` implementation, was to use an environment variable so that scripts run on the server could know which virtual host is being accessed.

Comment: The link is broken. Could you update the link?